# Can you store cargo on your outfit's "unused" spaces?

Tags: xia

In Xia: Legends of a Drift System, you can upgrade your ship with outfits.  These outfits take up several spaces in your cargo hold.  Many of the spaces on the outfits have game-significant features, such as arming points.  However, some of these spaces are effectively blank.  Is it legal to store cargo on top of these spaces in the outfits, or are they considered to be filled space?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot store cargo on the unused spaces of an outfit. The unused spaces are there to add complexity to the placement of your outfits and to also have a place for you to put damage on an outfit without it being disabled